# Install Ubuntu 20.04 on Asus G15

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I'm a frequent user of Ubuntu since 14.04. I have a hard time installing Ubuntu 20.04 on my new laptop. I have done the following.

- Disable Fast Boot in BIOS
- Disable Secure Boot in BIOS
- Make sure SATA connection is selected with the PCIe NVMe SSD
- Install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a USB drive via Rufus

A few specs about my laptop:

- Asus G15
- AMD R7-5800H
- NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti
- SSD

In the Grub menu, press `e` and put in `nouveau.modeset=0` as described in [here](https://liamfrappell.medium.com/fixing-black-screen-and-keyboard-shutdown-issues-on-an-asus-rog-strix-scar-2021-laptop-in-ubuntu-20-9ce964bf34d0) (if this is not done, then the resolution is 800x600 and I will have a harder time navigating with the unseen bottom of the install windows). All in all, it says I finished the installation. My problem is that it can't boot from the installed Ubuntu, it would just give me a black screen and do not advance from there. I have tried various ways, but I don't seem like I can break through here. Please let me know if there is anything else I can do to make this dual boot.

Update 1:

It actually works in Recovery Mode but not Normal Mode. I don't know why (perhaps the Nvidia drivers are not correct), but the installation procedure looks correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So these are the steps I follow to install Ubuntu 20.04 on Asus G15. The culprit is the graphics driver.

1. install without checking "Install third-party software".
2. boot in recovery mode
3. enable Networking
4. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
5. `sudo apt install nvidia-prime`
6. `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
7. create `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf`

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

8. edit `/etc/default/grub` and append `nomodeset` after `quite splash`
9. `sudo update-grub`
10. `sudo reboot now`

Notes:

1. I'm not sure if any commands above can be ignored.
2. Since you are logging in as a root shell, `sudo` is not required (because you are already a `root` user).
3. There are possibilities to install proprietary drivers

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

or

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460
```

but I did not take risks.

4. I have seen stuff like [this](https://liamfrappell.medium.com/fixing-black-screen-and-keyboard-shutdown-issues-on-an-asus-rog-strix-scar-2021-laptop-in-ubuntu-20-9ce964bf34d0) or [this](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-mate-20-04-with-rtx-3070-on-ryzen-5900-black-screen-after-boot/167681/29), which may be helpful, but probably not mandatory. It is still good to know though.